# SUSE 13.2 GRUB Configuration FIle

Tags: linux, opensuse, grub2

I just installed OpenSuse to learn it. I'd like to open the system in runtime 3 mode.
According to the [documentation](http://guillaume.gardet.free.fr/openSUSE-doc/opensuse-all/cha.grub.html) I have to edit /boot/grub/menu.lst file.

Unfortunately this file does not exist on my system.
Does anybody know why please? I need to do this to install my nvidia drivers, as X has not to be running while doing so.

Thanks.

Comment: does /etc/inittab exist?

Comment: Maybe you could stop X, install from char console, and then restart. To stop it, you had to stop the corresponding service with a system command (ideally from char console). You can switch to char console with alt/ctrl/f1 (and step back to X with alt/ctrl/f7 or alt/ctrl/f8).

Comment: Umm, doesn't openSUSE use systemd now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check /etc/inittab

```
$ grep -A1 default /etc/inittab 
# The default runlevel.
id:2:initdefault:
```

Adjust from 2 to 3 and that should be it.

Comment: There is no inittab in suse, it uses long systemd.

Comment: then maybe this link will help you adjust runlevel on system with systemd http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/FrequentlyAskedQuestions/

Comment: Yes, it is about systemd, but nothing from inittab. Although maybe it were useful for the asker.

Comment: The correct answer was to run the command:
Init 3